# How to keep explosive projectiles without propellants?

Tags: science-based, weapons, military, firearms

In the world i'm making, humans are physically incapable of producing propellants. Why? Because their God won't allow it. That doesn't mean humans stop searching for better ways to kill each other. So we ended up using *pneumatic guns*.

But is it possible to still create things like high explosive shells and rockets (or fireworks), even if you cannot produce propellants?

Thanks for your time and attention!

Edit: As far as I know, the biggest difference between high and low explosives are that low explosives Deflagrate, while high explosives Detonate. I really don't know if that helps.

Comment: do you mean propellant?

Comment: Torpedos, mines, slings, trebuchets, remote controlled vehicles (google for the German Goliath), suicide bombers, explosives attached to animals, long spears with explosives (bangalore torpedos, but also others)... All of those have been tried through history.

Comment: Railguns. Use electromagnets to launch a chunk of steel and you can theoretically have huge destructive power.

Comment: Depends on your God. Looks like they (gender neutral, hm) explicitly forbid [low explosives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosive#Low), but may be lenient about [high explosives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosive#High).

Comment: Strictly speaking, an explosive is a propellant, and the casing of a bomb is propelled. It becomes very definitional to determine what is or isn't a propellant. Is a claymore an explosive, or a big, directional gun with propellant? Does a steam cannon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_cannon Violate any of the rules? It would be more of a vehicle/fortification weapon.

Comment: You would need to clarify what you mean quite a bit to get the answer you want. Why not do as many of our members do and use google translate? It might help to clear-up contradictions like the difference between propeller and propellant. But you would also need to clarify why rockets are allowed, but propellants are not - a big contradiction here.

Comment: You mean no _chemical_ propellant, right? Pneumatic (air/water pressure based) should be fine? Also, how do your explosives work? NOTE: an explosive generates enough energy in a very short time to cause rapid expansion of gases, i.e., a propellant.

Comment: Prepare yourself for the Religious Caste engaging their God in endless debates over the fine print. So gunpowder is a propellant, but compressed air is not? How about Mentos in a Pepsi? How about dry ice being heated? How about an electric inductor heating a tungsten tube containing helium to 4500K? That will give you a gun with a low rate of fire, but a muzzle velocity of more than 6 km/s!! How about a nice electrical railgun, which is *easily* good for 2.5km/s, and could possibly be pushed up to 15km/s?

Comment: Yeah, I meant propellant, english is not my native language, so I'm very sorry if I messed up. I Don't know if separating explosives between those that deflagrate and those that detonate would make a difference.

Comment: Regarding "*separating explosives between those that deflagrate and those that detonate*", you're referring to what are termed low explosives vs high explosives, respectively.  I'm sorry to say that it doesn't help your proposed scenario: the early formulations of cordite, a propellant, were composed of more than half nitroglycerine, a high explosive that detonates.

Answer (score 5):

Frame challenge: it is impossible to prevent the creation of propellants without radically altering chemistry itself. Even table sugar (sucrose) can be used as a propellant with an appropriate oxidizer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_candy

Frame challenge #2: High explosives can be used as propellant either by modifying the combustion rate, e.g. by mixing other inert materials in or shaping the combustion surface, or the firing chamber pressure be manipulated to a usably low range, e.g. the high-low system (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High%E2%80%93low_system) used in some grenade launchers to turn a high-pressure explosion to a lower pressure explosion or the open-ended firing chamber of a recoilless rifle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recoilless_rifle).

Comment: Imho OP is quite clear that propellants are prohibited by the divine power. Yes, I presume the chemistry should be radically altered to achieve that, but we can exclude deflagration quite narrowly, without affecting biochemistry or metallurgy, for example .

Comment: @Alexander  Yes, I am aware of the prohibition and that is why the response is phrased as a frame challenge.

Comment: Downvote, because the question makes it clear that gods are involved, hence the situation need not conform to chemistry or physics as we know it.  Of course, that (IMO) makes the question unanswerable...

Comment: Frame challenge of the frame challenge : You don't need to change the laws of physics to prevent the use of propellants. Do the god's way : Throw some lightning strikes and launch a few earthquakes here and there against any propellant's trespasser.

Comment: @ZeissIkon  Unless I'm mistaken, that's what a frame challenge is for: providing reasons why the question is unanswerable as posed in as helpful a way as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> But is it possible to still create things like... rockets (or fireworks), even if you cannot produce propellants?

To a certain extent. You could conceivably make [steam rockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_rocket), for example, but given their relative complexity, difficult material requirements and unexciting performance compared to the simplest of solid fuel rockets it seems unlikely that anyone would try to use them for weapons.

You will probably not have anything resembling a firework *rocket*. It might be possible to make some ground-based fireworks by using compressed air to fire suitable burning materials into the air, but most of the stuff needed to make good fireworks is also stuff you can use to make propellants with.

> high explosive shells

Anything that's energetic enough to be used as an explosive is definitely useable as a propellant, up to and including [nuclear explosives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion)).

You could perhaps imagine using a [pressure cooker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_cooking) as a kind of bomb, also using steam, but again: you need a minimum level of metallurgy and machining to make a high pressure device, so they're no alternative for historical [mortars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortar_(weapon)#History) and the like. Their explosive yield is unlikely to match even quite poor low explosive charges, and they're certainly no substitute for high explosives. It would also take an annoyingly long time to go bang, and between being slow, obvious and low power its hard to see why anyone would bother.

---

Ultimately all that's left is either the existence of more reasonable deities (who will not have any trouble despatching the followers of your arms-control god, given that they'll have decent weapons) or hoping that the god grants certain exceptions. And they're gonna have to.

Huge swathes of chemistry and the industry that depends on it will be off limits, after all. Remember, alcohol could be a propellant, so no distillation, ever! Chemical fertilisers can be propellants, so none of those either. Almost all solvents other than water are forbidden (which forbids various kinds of paint, hampering artwork). Lots of antiseptics are off limits so even if you do develop germ theory it will be difficult to act upon it (making soap, you say? that glycerine byproduct is probably forbidden! lightning bolts are in your future).

Diesel engines work by making a suitable gas go bang and expanding to drive a piston. If you have airguns, you can cause [dieseling](https://airgunplanet.com/what-is-airgun-dieseling-and-how-dangerous-is-it-really/) easily. No-one has made a diesel cannon to my knowledge, but then *no-one has needed to*. Your unreasonable deity has created the perfect reason to try. Therefore, anything capable of being burnt in a diesel engine could be seen as a propellant! Does that mean that *vegetable oils* are forbidden, too? Probably! Diesel engines can also burn lard and tallow. So no candles or lamps for your dudes, as well as no fry-ups.

Remember that anything capable of forming a [BLEVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling_liquid_expanding_vapor_explosion) or [dust explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_explosion) could be used as a propellant. You can create a dust explosion with *flour*. Is grinding wheat going to be forbidden by your god?

You see the sort of problems you're up against here. Either you ban *everything*, and are left with people stuck in a weird primitive age without even the full range of technologies that the earliest prehistoric agricultural people had to hand, or you don't ban enough and everyone gets guns and bombs again.

Take home message:

**If you want fantasy arms control, don't do it this way!**